# Clone a Windows partition from a dual booted macine to a virtual machine

Tags: windows, grub2, virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot machine. I would like to clone the Windows partition to a virtual machine, so I can run it instead of having to reboot when I need to use some of the Windows-only software that is the only reason I keep it around for.

So far I've made a VDI image of the Windows partition succesfully, but I can't boot because the virtual machine has no EFI partition. I tried making a clone of the EFI partition from the host machine, but it has GRUB and expects to find the GRUB folders on my Linux partition and so it just dumps me out to the GRUB shell.

I then tried to point GRUB in the direction of my windows boot manager thingy:

```
set root=(hd0)
chainloader (hd0)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
```

But that failed with `unknown error`

How can I boot my virtual machine to my cloned windows partition?

Comment: In my opinion the easiest way to solve the boot problem is to first perform a clean Windows 10 install into the VM and then overwrite/replace the main Windows partition with the one from your harddisk. The Window installation creates all the necessary partitions and the bootloader you need from booting in the VM. Make sure you use the same installation method (UEFI vs. CSM mode for installing Windows into the VM as uses on your PC).

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm not sure about the details of how I do the swap exactly.